# WCF uploading Image to server Binding Error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have problem with WFC server or client config. 
When I try to upload Image to server I get error:

```
Content Type multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";
start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";
boundary="uuid:868d52b2-10f6-4661-8784-bf81f3a84c16+id=1";
start-info="application/soap+xml" was not supported by service http://localhost:8080/PhotoService/.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

Could someone help me to configure server and client or to tell me where did I get mistake?

I have such configuration:

On client side:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPhotoService" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2000000" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000">
                <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="50000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
                  <security mode="None">
                    <transport>
                      <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
                    </transport>
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/PhotoService/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPhotoService"
                contract="PhotoService.IPhotoService" name="WSHttpBinding_IPhotoService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

On Server side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PhotoService.PhotoService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PhotoService.IPhotoService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/PhotoService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize ="2000000" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="50000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport>
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client side sources:

```
private void AddPhoto()
        {
            try
            {
                Image image = Image.FromFile(WayToFile);
                var obj = new PhotoData();
                obj.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                obj.Image = Photo.ImageToByteArray(image);
                obj.Title = _title;
                obj.Description = _description;
                using (var service = new PhotoServiceClient())
                    service.InsertPhoto(obj);
                AllPhotos.Add(new Photo(obj));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }

        public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
        public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Server side sources:

```
[DataContract]
public class PhotoData
{
    private string _id;
    private string _title;
    private string _description;
    private byte[] _image;

    [DataMember]
    public string ID
    {
        set { _id = value; }
        get { return _id; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Title
    {
        set { _title = value; }
        get { return _title; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description
    {
        set { _description = value; }
        get { return _description; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Image
    {
        set { _image = value; }
        get { return _image; }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IPhotoService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void InsertPhoto(PhotoData photo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seens like you didn't set binding for server
In your server config add `bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"` to line 
`<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PhotoService.IPhotoService">`